# Generated PDF not send in the browser

Tags: spring, jsf

I build a PDF document with iText library, and i want to get this document by clicking a link in the webapp.
But, it happens... nothing. No error message, no exception, really nothing.
I really don't master IO Streaming, so I think I made a mistake on this point, but after few hours of research, I don't know and I need a bit of help.

I have two methods. The first is the one to create pdf doc.

```
public void exporterPDF(SomeObjectIWillUse o) {
    Document documentPDF = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documentPDF, baos);

        documentPDF.open();
        documentPDF.addTitle("Test ! ");
        Paragraph par = new Paragraph("Liste des participants");

        documentPDF.add(par)
        documentPDF.close();

        telechargerPdfViaVue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), baos, "filename.pdf");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JsfUtils.addMessageByCode(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "drc.export.generation.pdf.erreur");
    }

}
```

And the second is use to send the document.

```
public static final void telechargerPdfViaVue(FacesContext context, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String fileName) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Expires", "0");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Pragma", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    externalContext.setResponseContentLength(baos.size());
    OutputStream out = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(out);
    externalContext.responseFlushBuffer();
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

and it's called on my web page by a simple commandeLink

```
<p:commandLink id="exportPdf" action="#{myBean.exporterPDF(o)}">
```

Literally, in debug mode, all is done, but nothing happen... 
Thank you for your help!

More informations, I use :
- JSF 2.2.7
- Spring 4.0.6

Comment: do you want to show your pdf in a new blank page ?!?

Comment: mate try to put some printout around your code, that usually brings some lights

Comment: add `target="_blank"  ajax="false"` and see if it's working

Comment: I assume you debugged it on server. But what about browser? What does your response actually contain? How do you intend on showing the response?

Comment: Really... It was just due to `target="_blank"`, it not open automatically a webpage... I feel so stupid with my question about IO Streams. It's working now, so... thank you so much, and sorry for my ask so easy